# Math.Log(125,5) does not return 3 in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Why

```
var test = Math.Log(125,5);
Console.WriteLine(test % 1);
```

returns `4.44089209850063E-16`

Comment: Double precision floating point has a precision of [15-17 decimal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64), so an error of the order of `E-16` is not unexpected for a result in the units range.

Comment: [What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf) and [floating-point types precision in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types#characteristics-of-the-floating-point-types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the reference source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/math.cs), the important part of `Math.Log` works like this:

```
return (Log(a)/Log(newBase));
```

Where the single-argument `Log` computes the natural logarithm. This is a natural way to implement floating point logarithms for different bases. Natural logarithms are of course not exact in general, most of them aren't even rational numbers, and `double`s already can't exactly deal with arbitrary rational numbers let alone irrational numbers. There is no particular reason that the division between two such somewhat-inexact numbers results in an exact one, though it can happen. In this case, the result (bits of the `double` in hexadecimal) is 0x4008000000000001 while 3 would be 0x4008000000000000: it's off by the smallest possible amount that it could be off by.

For exact cases like `Log(125, 5)` the result could be calculated exactly, but that's not what `Math.Log` tries to do. If that's what you want, you can do it yourself.